# Add link within collapsible content header (split- link) - css missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have collapsible content, and would like to add a link that can be clicked besides the actual toggling function of the header.

[edit]Thanks to /frequent/, I am pretty close, the link "on" the header is working, but I am missing the css to get the link inside the header - just can't figure it out:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$( document ).on('pageinit','#page1', function (event) {
 $(".click_action").bind("click", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr('href'));
 });
});
</script>
<div data-role="page" id="page1"> 

<div data-role="collapsible" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed doublemeaning" data-enhanced="true">
<h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
<a class="myheading ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-plus" href="#">Heading</a>
<a class="click_action" href="test2.html">Go to test2.html</a>
</h3>
<div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
     <p>I'm the collapsible content. Open me!</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/XqAvB/1/
Any ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused, in your javascript the click is bound to an element with class ui-collapsible-heading-toggle but I don't see that element in the HTML. Is that the h3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in JQM 1.4 by enhancing the widget yourself, which means you need to set `data-enhanced="true"` on the collapsible and providing all collapsible-content yourself.

Normally an enhanced collapsible should have this code (using H4 header):

```
<div data-role="collapsible" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed">
    <h4 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
        <a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left" href="#">Heading<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
        </a>
    </h4>
    <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
         <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you provide this code yourself, JQM will only create the widget object on the collapsible and not enhance the widget. This way you can add multiple **pre-enhanced** buttons to the header element with JQM only enhancing the first (if I recall correctly).

Something like this:

```
    <h4 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
        <a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left" href="#">Heading<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
        </a>
        <a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-plus some_action" href="#">Make Foo</a>
    </h4>
```

Then CSS your button into the correct position, add your `some_action` click handler and don't forget to set a binding to `collapsibleexpand` event and `e.preventDefault` if the click was on your custom button (so check for `some_action` on `e.target`.

I had an example somewhere, but can't find it. If I do, I will add.

Comment: Thats almost it, great hint! But the "CSS your button" is easier said than done ;) Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XqAvB/2/). You have to enhance the 2nd button yourself - see the information on `data-enhanced` in JQM 1.4. Normally JQM will read all the data-foo attributes and generate classes (or needed elements) when creating the JQM widget. When setting `data-enhanced="true"` you are telling JQM that you generate the finished HTML = no need to read data- (slow) and manipulate DOM. For buttons it is easy, because it's just changing data-attributes into classes. The rest is some simple CSS. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: and mark the answer as checked if that was what you are looking for. Thanks :-)

Comment: Jupp, expect that I wanted the text in there and no button: http://jsfiddle.net/XqAvB/4/ I hope with em- and % values it stays where it is now on different devices & resolutions... time will tell I suppose! Thanks a lot for your help!