# How to add buttons to header of collapsible

Tags: jquery-mobile

Does somebody know the trick to put some bottoms in the header of a collapsible?

I try with this:
http://jsfiddle.net/84g5c/

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Header
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" class="lista">

        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c" class="collapsible">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d">
                <h3>
                    ¿How to put buttons here?           
                    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true">Delete</a>                    
                    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true">Add</a>                                     
                </h3>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" id="tarea1" class="tarea">
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                            Button1
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                            Button2
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                            Button3
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                            Button4
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

.ui-icon.ui-icon-delete.ui-icon-shadow{
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 0px !important;
}

.ui-btn.ui-shadow.ui-btn-corner-all.ui-btn-icon-notext.ui-btn-up-c{
    float: right !important;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add link within collapsible content header (split- link) - css missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331789/add-link-within-collapsible-content-header-split-link-css-missing)

Comment: @frequent answer covers jQM 1.4, this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/84g5c/1/ for jQM 1.3.2 and below.

Comment: Thank you both. I made some improvements here: http://jsfiddle.net/quvBs/ It works for me. But still there is a problem: when the collapsible is collapsed the row of buttons disappears ¿?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/quvBs/1/ (Better with a controlgroup)

Answer (score 0):

Asnwer for stealthed buttons, which I find more elegant. Should not be too hard to adapt in case you cant to see the button around the icon.

http://jsfiddle.net/YaQ29/

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b">
    <h2><p class=inline>ggggggggggg</p>
        <a class="inline coll_head_butt" data-theme="b" onclick="alert('clicked');" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button" data-icon="check"></a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inline{display:inline !important;}


.coll_head_butt{
    margin-left : 50px !important;
    /*padding:1em !important;*/
    border-style:none !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;
}
```

You could prevent the button from expanding the collapsible if needed.

Comment: Well just saw the date.